# Permission request not showing on ios for location sharing

Tags: google-maps, react-native, geolocation, authorization, frontend

I have been trying to make the location permission request work. Initially, it did, but after resetting the simulator and trying other simulators in ios it did not show up again. I've reset the devices to test it out again just to make sure. Below are the info.plist and the code in the concerned sections. Thanks for trying

info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>mApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
      <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
      <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
          <true/>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
      <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
      <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
      <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
      <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
      <string>Feather.ttf</string>
      <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
      <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
      <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
      <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
      <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
      <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
      <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
      <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
      <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
      <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
      <string>location</string>
      <string>fetch</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
      <string>CHANGEME: Location Always Usage Description</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>CHANGEME: Location Always Usage Description</string>
    <key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
    <string>CHANGEME: Motion updates increase battery efficiency by intelligently toggling location-services when device is detected to be moving</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Code:

```
class Home extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    navigator.geolocation.requestAuthorization()
  }
  render(){

    return(
   <View style={styles.container}>

     <MapView showUserLocation={true}
     // remove if not using Google Maps
     customMapStyle={mapStyle}
     provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} 
       style={styles.map}
       region={{
         latitude: 37.78825,
         longitude: -122.4324,
         latitudeDelta: 0.015,
         longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
       }}
     >


     </MapView>

     <MenuIcon navigation={this.props.navigation}/>

   </View>
)
     }}

     export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
      {
       Home: Home,
       Other: Altern
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
      }
    ));
```

Settings:

[image]

Comment: I've reset the device so I had access but after resetting and re-running the device it restarts from scratch. I checked my settings and there are no permissions available.

Comment: it should work, try to delete xcode derived data.

Comment: Just did what you said but same result, I have just posted the settings page for anyone that wants to confirm it isn't active

Comment: <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>

try with those keys